# Formatting of Webbrowser text

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

Here is my problem. 
I have a webbrowser in my c# winforms application. I'm loading a html file in it in design mode to edit the html after loading. After I load the html, I'm selecting text and formatting it. 
When I select text and do - cut, copy, paste, undo, redo, bold, italic, underline command operations on the selected text, it works fine. 
However, when I do justifyleft, justifyright, justifycenter, indent, outdent operations, the whole page gets altered, rather than only the selected text.

Below is the code i'm using to select the range from the browser.

```
    private IHTMLTxtRange getRange(IHTMLSelectionObject selection)
    {
        if (selection != null)
        {
            IHTMLTxtRange range = selection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
            return range;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void executeBrowserCommand(string command)
    {
        sRange = getRange(htmlDoc.selection);
        if (sRange != null && sRange.htmlText != "")
        {
            sRange.execCommand(command, false, null);
        }
    }
```

Any advice why the operations are being performed on the whole page instead of the selected text only? Thanks.

Comment: Any help? No more than 17 view from past 3 days, and no suggestions. Hence, removing the webbrowser tag from the question for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

When you apply the "justify" flags they apply to the block the selection is contained within.  I guess your selection is not an individual block element. For example the documentation for fit justifies states:

> Right-justifies the format block in which the current selection is located.

See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: When I specify the "JustifyCenter" for the range selected, it is being applied for the whole document in the webbrowser control and not for only the selected text. :(
I also referred the link below before I coded the execute command section. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the HTML document in the question as well as the region selected. Would It be possible to post a minimal complete example?